# How to input eps_tex from subdirectory?

Tags: input, eps

I have the following directories:

```
 maindir
  '-thesis.tex
  '-figures
      '-drawing.eps_tex
      '-drawing.eps
```

My thesis.tex looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}

\begin{document}

\input{figures/drawing.eps_tex} 

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `drawing.eps' not found on input line 52.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `drawing-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

If I have the drawing in the `maindir`, the error does not occur and the `drawing-eps-converted-to.pdf` is build and everything works as expected. Apparently, there is some implicit `input{}` for the mentioned file from a script that thinks it is executed in the `maindir`.

How to fix this? I have a lot of figures and don't want to keep them in the `maindir`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `\graphicspath` fixed it:

```
\graphicspath{{\curdir figures/}}
```